# Is it possible to inspect network activity by element

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am now taking over a web backend project with existing frontend. Every time when I load the page the list of network activities is extremely long, especially for dashboard. Is it possible to show requests posted by one element of the page?

Comment: Is the frontend using a framework?

Comment: Yes. Frontend is using ReactJS